# In Matlab, getting error "TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0"

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am making a function that takes an image and a luminance range and then returns an intensity sliced image. So essentially it detects if a certain pixel's intensity is in the range and then sets the intensity to 255 so it's bright white, or otherwise leaves it alone. The equation for luminance I'm given is `L = 0.3R + 0.59G + 0.11B`. I think everything is executed correctly, but when I try to use the built in `image` function to turn the intensities into an image I get the error in the title. Here is my code so far.

```
function finalImage = nicholson11(image,range)

originalImage = imread(image);
[W,H,clrs] = size(originalImage);
finalImage = zeros(W,H,3);

for i=1:1:W
for j=1:1:H
if ((((originalImage(i,j,1))*0.3) +((originalImage(i,j,2))*0.59) +((originalImage(i,j,3))*0.11)) >=range(1) && ((((originalImage(i,j,1))*0.3) +((originalImage(i,j,2))*0.59) + ((originalImage(i,j,3))*0.11))<=range(2)))
finalImage(i,j,:)=255;

end
end
end
```

Comment: At which point of code are you getting this error - `“TrueColor CData ..`?

Comment: I made a quick test program where I just did x=nicholson11('image.jpg',[50 100])

image(x)

and doing this returns the error

Comment: From the 'image()' doc: "For matrices containing doubles, color intensities are on the range [0.0, 1.0].  For uint8 and uint16 matrices, color intensities are on the range [0, 255]". So you either need to scale you double image into the range [0 1], or convert it to uint.

Comment: Or just switch to using `imagesc` which will scale the image for you

Comment: There is also a small but fundamental error in your code (to which I suggested an edit).  As you originally created your image to have three channels, in your `for` loop you should assign **ALL** channels to be 255.  You originally had `finalImage(i,j)` which would only assign the red channel to be 255 while leaving the other channels alone.  As such, either index the third channel with having a `:` in your loop or change the declaration of your image so that it is 2D instead of 3D.  In any case, the suggestions by Ghaul and Raab70 are perfectly valid.  Also take a look at my answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider vectorizing your code to make it more legible and less obfuscated.  You can completely avoid `for` loops by doing the following:

```
function finalImage = nicholson11(image,range)

imDouble = double(image);

intensityImage = 0.3*imDouble(:,:,1) + 0.59*imDouble(:,:,2) + 0.11*imDouble(:,:,3);
finalImage = zeros(size(intensityImage));
finalImage(intensityImage >= range(1) | intensityImage <= range(2)) = 255;

% Assuming your original image was uint8
finalImage = im2uint8(finalImage);
```

Try that and see if you get the same results.  Also, going with the comments that have already been said, when you create `finalImage`, this is a `double` array, which assumes that the intensities are between `[0,1]`.  As such, you will either need to normalize your intensities so that they fall in this range, or use a conversion routine that will get it to the type that you want.  Assuming that your image was originally `uint8`, you can use the `im2uint8` command.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't store brightness values into `finalImage`.

Comment: Yup... you're right about that.  My mistake.  Easy fix.  Thanks for the spot.